# How to inject component tag using innerHTML directive?

Tags: angular

I have some collection of objects, in which each object has the following property:

```
{
...
component: '<example-component></example-component>'
}
```

And in my `*ngFor` directive, I have the following:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
   <div [innerHTML]="item.component">
   </div>
</div>
```

However, this seems not to inject the component. Am I doing something wrong here?

Btw, If I change the component to SVG (which is basically what I want to achive), it doesn't render as well.

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468

Comment: HTML passed as `[innerHtml]` or any other dynamic way is not processed by Angular2 in any way (except some sanitization). You need to use `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` if you want to dynamically instantiate and add components.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, is it possible to use `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` in *ngFor?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468 does this

Comment: Works great @GünterZöchbauer. Danke Schon!

Comment: Gerne :) . . . . .